# Programming mote using TinyOS getting error (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: tinyos

I'm programming the MSP-430 mote using the command telosb. I'm stumbled in the error showed below:

```
root@andrea-VirtualBox:/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tinyos-main/apps/Blink# make telosb reinstall bsl,/dev/ttyUSB0
cp build/telosb/main.ihex build/telosb/main.ihex.out
    installing telosb binary using bsl
tos-bsl --telosb -c /dev/ttyUSB0 -r -e -I -p
build/telosb/main.ihex.out
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-goodfet-8
Mass Erase...
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-goodfet-8<br>
Mass Erase...<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 1918, in <module>
    main(0);
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 1833, in main
    for f in toinit: f()
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 1098, in actionMassErase
    0xa506)             #Required setting for mass erase!
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 758, in bslTxRx
    rxFrame = self.comTxRx(cmd, dataOut, len(dataOut))  #Send frame
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 440, in comTxRx
    rxHeader, rxNum = self.comRxHeader()       #receive header
  File "/home/andrea/local/bin/tos-bsl", line 346, in comRxHeader
    if not hdr: raise BSLException("Timeout")
__main__.BSLException: Timeout
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tinyos-main/support/make/msp /bsl.extra:45: recipe for target 'program' failed
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

How can I solve this?
I'm spending days on that :(

Comment: Firstly, I think this is the wrong forum for your question, it's about an MSP430 toolchain, and the software isn't from the Ubuntu repositories. You are more likely to get an answer in an electronics or programming Q&A site. Secondly, you are working inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`! You should be working in your home directory, not inside the configuration folder for apt!

Comment: Hi @Andrea Strappato, it looks like you are using VirtualBox. Is there any chance you could use this tool from a real machine? There may be a delay or issue with the VirtualBox USB passthrough driver, especially if your MCU resets in between erases (which it looks like it does). Even if you don't want to install Ubuntu, you could make a persistent live USB or install to an external HDD.

Comment: I followed your first suggestion working in the opt folder, btw as expected this can't solve the issue. Maybe the solution is to use a real OS as you said. I'll wait other anwers before to close the topic. thx!